# visual studio 2013 update 4 crashes on adding control

Tags: vb.net

when i add a control to the designer in vb.net windows application the program crashes and restarts then it does it again i have tried to uninstall and reinstall / repair / trying different version (i had express , tired ultimate .. still same issue)

visual studio 2013 update 4

When i click on the debug option (not in vb in , in the error) the (second image) happened it is an error in system drawing but how to fix it ?

thanks in advance

first image : i.imgur.  com/BGb5QKL.png  (remove space)

second image : i.imgur.  com/8Bho7rr.png (remove space)

edit(1): tried launching it in safe mode using the dev command prompt still no luck 
edit(2): the problem happens instantly when adding tabcontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that the anti-virus kaspersky 2015 was interfering with visual studio so simply uninstalling it solved the issue